# Convert String to Date in old version javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to convert a string to date in an old version of javascript, however, it is not working.

When I ran it using node v16, then it worked well:

```js
var tt = "2021-04-24T17:18:29.000"
var createDate = new Date(tt);
console.log(createDate) //2021-04-24T20:18:29.000Z
console.log(createDate.getDate()) //24
```

**However, when I am running the same code in an old version of JS that I don't know what JS version is, I am sure that is an old one because it does not accept "let" for instance, then I get an error: "Invalid Date" and "NaN"**

```js
var tt = "2021-04-24T17:18:29.000"
var createDate = new Date(tt);
var x1 = createDate;
var x2 = createDate.getDate();

console.log( "createDate>> " + createDate +  " || x1 " + x1 + " x2 " + x2)
//result createDate>> Invalid Date || x1 Invalid Date x2 NaN
```

Can someone give a tip to convert this string into a date?

Comment: Prior to ECMAScript 2011 (ed 5), the built–in parser was only required to parse the formats produced by *Date.prototype.toString* and *Date.prototype.toUTCString*. Parsing of any other format was implementation dependent. The format in the OP is not consistent with either of those formats. ECMAScript 2011 added support for the format produced by *toISOString*, with which the OP is consistent. So the script engine is likely dated prior to ECMAScript 2011 (e.g. [*ECMA-262 ed 3*](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_3rd_edition_december_1999.pdf) from 1999).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Date() constructor syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax) `new Date(year, monthIndex, day, hours, minutes, seconds)`

```js
function dateStringToDate(dateString) {  
  var parts = dateString.split('T');
  
  var dateParts = parts[0].split('-');
  var year = parseInt(dateParts[0], 10);
  var month = parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1;
  var day = parseInt(dateParts[2], 10);
  
  var timeParts = parts[1].split(':')
  var hours = parseInt(timeParts[0], 10);
  var minutes = parseInt(timeParts[1], 10);
  var seconds = parseInt(timeParts[2], 10);
  
  return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds);  
}

var tt = "2021-04-24T17:18:29.000";
var dateObj = dateStringToDate(tt);
console.log(dateObj);
```